# Firebase Auth Are my variables secure/safe?

Tags: node.js, firebase, heroku, socket.io, firebase-authentication

I am currently using heroku to store my environmental variables for my firebase authentication initialisation. I am using my server to get the environmental variables and send it to the client using socket.io. Below is what I mean.

1) Example of sending environmental variable to client from server:

```
socket.emit('value', process.env.apiKey);
```

2) storing it as data[0] in the client:

```html
socket.on('value', function(data) {
firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: data[0],
});
})
```

Is this safe? Can someone from the client retrieve the value of the apiKey if I save it like this on the client?

Thanks

Comment: The data that you pass to `initializeApp` is basic configuration data. It is not secret, not a security mehcanism and can be safely shared with your users. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: But my question was can people see this data value?

Comment: It the value exists in the client, malicious users can get at it. Not hard-coding the config inside the client merely adds one extra step.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is used from the client, it can be gotten from there by a malicious user. Looking up the data dynamically like you do here, merely adds an extra step.

But the data that you pass to `initializeApp` is basic configuration data that allows the code to find your Firebase project on the servers. It is not a secret, it's not a security mechanism ,and it can be safely shared with your users. See my answer here, for why you don't have to try and secure this data: [Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public)